# how does new Function() initialise this

Tags: javascript, function, constructor

I'm looking for information on how is initialised the value of *this* when using the *new Function()* constructor.

I've tested it on node 10.24.0 and it looks like the behaviour is the same as for lambas(arrow functions) : no *this* is set because no closure is built.

Is my guessing correct ?

here is the simple test :

```
> let o = { 'a' : 1, f : new Function('return this;') };
> o;
{ a: 1, f: [Function: anonymous] }
> o.f();
{ a: 1, f: [Function: anonymous] }
```

Comment: `this` is not set at creation time, it's determined at call time. Moreover, `this` is in no way related to closures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, this is not correct, as your own test confirms. `Function()` creates a normal function, not an arrow, therefore no `this` binding takes place at the creation time.

```js
let o = { 
  'a' : 1, 
  x: function() { return this },
  y : new Function('return this;'), 
  z: () => { return this } 
  };

console.log(o.x() === o) // yes
console.log(o.y() === o) // yes
console.log(o.z() === window) // yes
```